# Locate env.example in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to rename .env.example to .env but I cannot locate such file/folder in my new Laravel 5 Project. Not to mention I am just starting with Laravel framework.

I am trying to fix the error: "Whoops, looks like something went wrong" when accessign laravel/public

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it should be at the very root of the default Laravel installation. Like:

```
 - /app
 - /bootstrap
 - /...
 - /tests
 - .env.example     <<<<<
 - .gitattributes
```

If yours is missing for some reason, you can just grab the `.example` from github:
[laravel/laravel - .env.example](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/.env.example)

Comment: Yeah, your solution helped fix THIS problem. Thank you very much. Now it displays the error which is "FatalErrorException in compiled.php line 5657:
Call to undefined function Illuminate\Support\ctype_lower()". Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Looks like the ctype extension is missing. You need to install/enable it. I'm sure google will help you with this. Also please accept my answer since I answered your actual question :)

Comment: I did accept your answer, but I wasn't able before. It kept saying you can accept answer in x minutes. So I had to wait. Sorry for that

Comment: Yes I know. You have to wait at least 15 minutes after asking the question. Just wanted to make sure you don't forget it ;)

Comment: I voted you up again because of your further indication on the ctype. I have it installed with AMPPS but was not activated. OK. I think I'm up and running.

Answer (score 0):

.env.example is present in every laravel 5 app. It may be hidden considering that it is prefixed with a dot;